# How to escape from vim - in Linux?

Tags: linux

I was trying to read a content of a file which is called -. Instead of enter vim ./-, I accidentally enter vim - 
And it generate the following command: 
E326: Too many swap files found Vim: Reading from stdin...

I can type any thing bellow the line; however, I can not escape the vim to my home directory.

Comment: I tried :q! but it does not work, and when I hit Esc, it assumes that I enter the symbol ^[

Comment: Just close the terminal emulator.

Comment: `Control+C -> Enter`, should bring you to Vim interface, then `:q!`

Comment: that is easy, but do you know a command to actually escape that

Comment: Thanks Matt Clark

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

By entering

```
vim -
```

The process is now taking its input from *stdin*;

To quit into the Vim interface, press `Control+C -> Enter`.

From here, you should be able to quit using `:q`